# Retrieve data attribute from div

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

I know how to get a data attribute using .data('id') for example..
But I cannot figure out how to get the "attachment_id" value contained within "data-kgvid_video_vars" ?

this is what im trying to get it into so I can then use it elsewhere..

```
 alert(jQuery(this).find('.kgvid_videodiv').data('id'));



data-kgvid_video_vars='{"id":"kgvid_16","attachment_id":116,"player_type":"Video.js","width":"640","height":"360","fullwidth":"true","countable":true,"count_views":"start_complete","start":"","autoplay":"false","pauseothervideos":"true","set_volume":"1","mute":"false","meta":true,"endofvideooverlay":"","resize":"true","auto_res":"automatic","pixel_ratio":"true","right_click":"on","playback_rate":"false","nativecontrolsfortouch":"false","locale":"en","enable_resolutions_plugin":false}'
```

Comment: what is data-kgvid_video_vars ?? is this a variable or something else?
you cannot use `-`  in variable name, please fix your question before posting..

Comment: <div id="video_kgvid_16_div" data-id="kgvid_16" data-kgvid_video_vars='{"id":"kgvid_16","attachment_id":116,"player_type":"Video.js","width":"640","height":"360","fullwidth":"true","countable":true,"count_views":"start_complete","start":"","autoplay":"false","pauseothervideos":"true","set_volume":"1","mute":"false","meta":true,"endofvideooverlay":"","resize":"true","auto_res":"automatic","pixel_ratio":"true","right_click":"on","playback_rate":"false","nativecontrolsfortouch":"false","locale":"en","enable_resolutions_plugin":false}'></div>

Comment: its just within the div in the source, its dynamic so I dont control it, just need to pull out that 3 digit id

Comment: okay i got it, please wait

Comment: i need to use it within

Comment: jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.gallery-right .kgvid_wrapper').click(function(){
    alert(jQuery(this).find('.kgvid_videodiv').data('id'));
    // or alert($(this).hash();
  });
});

Answer (score -1):

To getting values of an attribute from a html component:

```
kgvid_video_vars= jQuery(this).find('.kgvid_videodiv').data('kgvid_video_vars');
```

To getting values of a json variable in javascript:

```
kgvid_video_vars= '{"id":"kgvid_16","attachment_id":116}';
jsonData = JSON.parse(kgvid_video_vars);

alert(jsonData.attachment_id);
```

See the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

To fulfil answer your question

```
kgvid_video_vars= jQuery(this).find('.kgvid_videodiv').data('kgvid_video_vars');
jsonData = JSON.parse(kgvid_video_vars);

alert(jsonData.attachment_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I havnt got a clue how to use that within my jquery function..

Answer (score -1):

```
var data-kgvid_video_vars = JSON.parse(jQuery(this).find('.kgvid_videodiv').data('data-kgvid_video_vars'));
alert(data-kgvid_video_vars["attachment_id"])
```

Comment: its sooo wrong..try this one on javascript console will show an error..and my answer is better still got 0 point.. -__-